# How to fetch data from api and pass it as props

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the learning phase of react and trying to figure out how to
 fetch api data and pass it as props, so i created my own api file in
 github and tried to fetch the api data from it, here is the link
 below:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faizalsharn/jokes_api/master/jokesData.js

for some reason the data is not being fetched from the api and not
 being passed as props could someone, please explain me where im doing
 wrong, forgive me if there is any obvious mistakes here im still in
 beginner level

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import Joke from "./joke"

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            jokeComponents: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faizalsharn/jokes_api/master/jokesData.js")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    jokeComponents: data.jokesData.map(joke => <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />)  
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : this.state.jokeComponents
        return (
            <div>
                {text}   
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

**joke.js**

```
import React from "react"

function Joke(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3 style={{display: !props.question && "none"}}>Question: {props.question}</h3>
            <h3 style={{color: !props.question && "#888888"}}>Answer: {props.punchLine}</h3>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Joke
```

Comment: it just prints out loading.. and does not print the api data

Comment: I think there is a problem with your JSON, hence the data is not being populated. Fix your JSON by wrapping keys with double inverted commas. Like change id to "id" and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gideon Arces correctly explained your first bug, but there's more to do:

- You need to format your .json file as json, which is not the same as javascript.
  For example, while this is javascript `{id: 1, question: "?"}` it's not json. Json must be formatted like this: `{"id": "1", "question":"?"}` with quotes around the property names.
- You need to do your data fetching in your componentDidMount and call setState there
- You need to pull data from the state and render your components in `render()`. Typically this is done by creating an array of components and then putting them into the return inside `{}`. See more on that here: [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)
- It's always a good idea to start with dummy data hardcoded into your component before you try to combine your ui with your api. See below in the `componentDidMount()` where I hardcoded some jokes. This way you can isolate bugs in your ui code from those in your network/api code.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            jokes: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this.setState({loading: true})
        //     fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faizalsharn/jokes_api/master/jokesData.js")
        //         .then(response => response.json())
        //         .then(data => {
        //             console.log(data);
        //             this.setState({
        //                 loading: false,
        //                 jokes: data
        //             })
        //         })
        const json = `[
      {
          "id": "1",
          "question": "?",
          "punchLine": "It’s hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they always take things literally."
      },
      {
          "id": "2",
          "question": "What's the best thing about Switzerland?",
          "punchLine": "I don't know, but the flag is a big plus!"
      }
  ]`;

        const jokes = JSON.parse(json);
        this.setState({ jokes });
    }

    render() {
        const jokeComponents = this.state.jokes.map(joke => (
            <Joke key={joke.id} question={joke.question} punchLine={joke.punchLine} />
        ));
        console.log(jokeComponents);
        const text = this.state.loading ? "loading..." : jokeComponents;
        return <div>Text: {text}</div>;
    }
}

function Joke(props) {
    console.log("joke props:", props);
    return (
        <div>
            <h3 style={{ display: !props.question && "none" }}>
                Question: {props.question}
            </h3>
            <h3 style={{ color: !props.question && "#888888" }}>
                Answer: {props.punchLine}
            </h3>
            <hr />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I check the API, and found out that it is not working properly when the `response.json()` is being invoke in the fetch API.

And this is due to the error in the response of the API. You just need to return a bare array, and not return the API with a variable.

[image]

For reference, please check the return json of the Jsonplaceholder Fake API. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Hope this fix your error.

Also, for the state of the jokeComponents, please just have the array passed in the response, and not manipulate the data. Just use the `.map` for the jokeArray in the `render()` function if the state is changed. :)

Comment: Also, the first joke, id 1, has no question, haha!

Comment: @Gideon Arces, i have changed the api as you suggested, now it just return the bare array but still the it prints just loading..., could you please explain in code about the 2nd point! im not that much of an expert in react

Comment: JSON format is not the same as javascript. Your json needs to be formatted like this: "id": "1", "question": "...", "answer": "..."

Comment: @Mark The first joke doesn't have a punchline, it's a one-liner joke :) The full text reads "It's hard to explain puns to kleptomaniacs because they take things literally"

Answer (score 1):

To show content after it is being loaded and hide the loading indicator, use a function that simulates an async action and after that the data will be shown. I've shown this example with another API, as there is a problem with your API. I hope you fix that. Also set headers to allow *cross domain* data access.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Joke from "./Joke";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      jokeComponents: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",{
      headers: { crossDomain: true, "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    }).then(response=>response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          jokeComponents: data.map(joke => (
            <Joke
              key={joke.id}
              question={joke.title}
              punchLine={joke.body}
            />
          ))
        });
      });
      demoAsyncCall().then(() => this.setState({ loading: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;

    if(loading) { 
      return "loading...";
    }
    return <div>{this.state.jokeComponents}</div>;
  }
}

function demoAsyncCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2500));
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The working code of the same is set up in CodeSandbox below:

[image: Edit React example]